# Can't configure pom.xml for serenity+jbehave

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I got these error while trying to perform:

`mvn clean verify -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome`

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (verify) on project serenity-jbehave-showcase: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
[ERROR] Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
[ERROR] Dependency convergence error for com.google.guava:guava:19.0 paths to dependency are:
[ERROR] +-net.serenitybdd.showcase:serenity-jbehave-showcase:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] +-net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.2.2
[ERROR] +-com.google.guava:guava:19.0
[ERROR] and
[ERROR] +-net.serenitybdd.showcase:serenity-jbehave-showcase:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] +-net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.2.2
[ERROR] +-net.serenity-bdd:serenity-report-resources:1.2.2
[ERROR] +-com.google.guava:guava:19.0
[ERROR] and
```

and etc.

What do I have to change in pom.xml to run my test just using `mvn clean verify -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome`?

My pom.xml is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "and etc." you reference probably has some more relevant info. Going by what you have, though, this looks like you have multiple dependencies on `guava`, and not all of them are the same version. (Note that some of them may be *transitive* dependencies: those that are included as a dependency by another dependency).

The `maven-enforcer-plugin` detects when a single library has multiple versions specified, and it breaks the build. If you're just trying to run a quick test, though, you can probably add `-Denforcer.skip=true`. **This is not recommended for long-term use**, but only for running your single test.

Long-term, you will ultimately need to use Maven's `dependencyManagement` to force a specific version of Guava to be used, overriding the version mismatch.